# Event callback while changing input value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a input field with number type:

```
<input type = "number" v-model="numberOfTransport">
```

and here is the data:

```
data: function () {
  return {
          numberOfTransport: 2,
     }
},
```

and here getting each value by every input:

```
watch : {
  numberOfTransport(value){
   this.$emit('numberOfTransport', value);
   console.log(value);
  }
},
```

In such method I would like to set that value to another variable called “layerMultiplier” so by every input the value of “layerMultiplier” has to get “numberOfTransport”

I defined this variable like this:

```
let layerMultiplier = parseInt(this.numberOfTransport);
```

and I added: this.layerMultiplier = value;

```
watch : {
  numberOfTransport(value){
   this.$emit('numberOfTransport', value);
   this.layerMultiplier = value;
   console.log(this.layerMultiplier);
  }
},
```

the “layerMultiplier” is getting the value “2” as is defined it in data, the problem is how to set that variable. I guess it’s missing somehow to set "layerMultiplier" by using callback function! Does anybody can help me?

Comment: Have you checked that the `value` variable is not = 2 ? Have you defined `layerMultiplier ` in `data()` ?

Comment: From your question it is not clear what is going wrong. Provide a working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Juky yes the value is not =2, is getting the value of input! and also when layerMultiplier is defined in data() still the same problem

Comment: stdob-- I edited the question.

Comment: I tested your code but don't see any problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwbgpac/

Comment: I know, but when I use layerMultiplier in any method is getting always "0" and not the value of input    `slider.onValueChangedObservable.add(function(value) {
   
        value = Math.round(value) * this.layerMultiplier;
        header.text = "Day: " + value;
        if(tower){
            let height = tower._index.length;
            if(height < value){
                tower.createLayers( value - height );
            }
            else if(height > value){
                tower.disposeLayer(height - value, true);
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/24w7922m70

the “layerMultiplier” is getting the value “3” as is defined by default it in data, so while changing the number of input nothing ill change. The problem is how to set that variable? I guess it’s missing somehow to set “layerMultiplier” by using callback function!

PS: the component is called Tower.vue and in case of any kind of this problem Error in nextTick: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘AdvancedDynamicTexture’ of undefined” just do any changment in the code even space, then will work!